# Symfony 4 use global criteria for entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I use Symfony 4.1, and I need to get results from my DB excluding some criterias.

For now, I use the query in my repo :

```
 ->andWhere('p.status != :sold')
 ->setParameter('sold', STATUS_SOLD)
 ...
```

But I suppose it's not the good way, since I need to handle all queries and relations.

I thought about Listener/Subscriber, and `postLoad` event. I don't know if it's the correct way since the doc is very poor.

What is the best way to apply criteria for an entity for the whole application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Doctrine Filters documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html) In your case you will write something like

```
if (!$targetEntity->reflClass->implementsInterface('SoldAware')) {
    return "";
}

return $targetTableAlias.'.status <> ' . Statuses::STATUS_SOLD;
```

Comment: It's very nice, but I don't get how to build the SoldAware interface now, I will check. Thanks

Comment: @VincentDecaux you can skip SoldAware interface so filter will be applied to all entities. Or it can be just empty interface and only filter needed entities will implement it

Comment: Yes I missread your answer and the code. Perfect solution, thanks